# MySQL access denied in PHP, CLI will connect

Tags: php, mysql, iis-7

At first I tried just connecting with PDO in PHP. However, I get access denied messages. I can use the exact same commands to connect to the command line interface, but php gives this error from PDO:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'avt_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php(3): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'avt_root', '[**]') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 3

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=AVT_TIME", "avt_root", "[**]");
```

So next I tried just connecting with mysql_connect to troubleshoot maybe having the PDO parameters incorrect:

```
$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "avt", "[**]");
```

However, even this gives me pretty much the same error:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'avt'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 2

Server Configuration:
IIS7.0 with PHP running under fast_cgi and MySQL installed with correct extensions chosen in php.ini file.

Any and all help is appreciated, minus any comments regarding correct username and password, I have checked and triple checked for both the avt_root and avt accounts. The password for both is actually the same, and both can log in via the CLI over remote desktop.

Comment: Is the mysql db being hosted from the same machine running the web server/php?

Comment: Yes it is, same machine. As I stated by Server Configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up on this and completely reinstalled MySQL and am just going to use the root account, as we have high enough security that I don't have to worry too much about someone messing with an intranet only site.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` can be a little wonky in mysql-land. The standard mysql interface library, which `mysql_*()` functions use, internally redefine `localhost` to be a local unix-domain socket connection. This is purey for efficiency, as unix sockets do not have the overhead that TCP sockets do.

PDO, which is probably using mysqlnd, will not have that problem. localhost will mean 127.0.0.1 and it'll be trying to use a TCP socket.

Make sure that your `avt` account is set up as `avt@127.0.0.1` to allow TCP connections.

Comment: Just tried this, I cannot connect using the MySQL_ functions nor PDO, still.